# Mysql SP with custom arguments

Tags: mysql, stored-procedures

Im new to mysql stored procedure. Here I have a table **tbl_users** with following fields

```
id
first_name
last_name
status
```

I have written following SP to update this table.

```
CREATE PROCEDURE `user_update`(IN var_id INT, IN var_first_name TEXT, IN var_last_name TEXT, IN var_status INT)
BEGIN    
    UPDATE tbl_users SET first_name = var_first_name, last_name = var_last_name, status = var_status WHERE id = var_id;
END
```

The above procedure will work fine. The problem, I want to use the same procedure to update the only **status** field. In this situation I have to pass all params with existing values.  Is there any solution, If possible I can reuse the SP in multiple areas... pls help.

Answer (score 1):

```
Mr. EKL please try this code,
You have to include a new parameter "Update_Field"  and try the below code

CREATE PROCEDURE `user_update`(
IN var_id INT, 
IN var_first_name TEXT, 
IN var_last_name TEXT, 
IN var_status INT,
IN Update_field TEXT
)
BEGIN    
UPDATE tbl_users SET first_name = var_first_name, last_name = var_last_name, [status] = var_status WHERE id = var_id AND Update_field = 'ALL'; 
UPDATE  tbl_users SET [status]  = var_status WHERE  id = var_id AND Update_field = 'status';
END
```

Comment: Its a good solution, is it possible to pass arguments as an array?